# When do I notate the midpoint of a measure?

Tags: notation

Is it necessary to notate measures in such a way as to always delineate the third count in 4/4 time or the fourth count in 6/4 or 6/8 time, in other words to show the midpoint of the measure?

Comment: Not really, but if you expect people to put effort into answering your question you should put some effort into asking a good question. A good question would be clearly defined, well phrased and might give some context.

Comment: I thought there were no dumb questions.  I hope that someone can give me some context in which the midpoint of a measure should be clearly delineated.  It's a rule which has been suggested to me in writing for choirs or vocal soloists as I've been told that singers need to see the midpoint of the measure, but I'm not sure how far to carry that rule of thumb.  This is a functional question, not a purely hypothetical one.

Comment: It's not a dumb question. But it's not entirely clear to me: In what way are you thinking of notating or delineating? Sometimes one encounters dotted bar lines for various reasons, but that's rarely done in every measure. Or maybe this is a question about beaming or other notational ways of aligning with metric structure?

Comment: It’s not about dumb or not dumb. It’s about clearly specifying your question to make it easier for people to answer. It’s about putting some effort into asking your question, as you’d probably expect people to put in some effort to answer it. I’m not saying so to reprimand you, but to give you some pointers. You will find that a question will be much more likely to be answered if you put in some effort to make it a good question.

Comment: "Is it necessary to notate measures in such a way as to always delineate...": Clearly the answer is _no_ because we can trivially identify cases where it is wrong to do so, for example when the measure is filled by a single note (such as a whole note in 4/4).  A better question might be "when is it necessary to notate measures so as to delineate..."

Comment: @phoog - which is where the header comes in..!

Comment: The header somewhat contradicts the essence of the question itself. Needs a little clarification - more to the question than the header.

Comment: Mary:  you have created two accounts.  You can [merge](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.  This will allow you to comment on the answers to your question, among other things.

Answer (score 3):

Start from the basic premise 'show the beats, show the mid-point of the bar.    Then explore the exceptions!

It's summed up pretty well on p.166 of Gould's 'Behind Bars', probably the nearest we have to a current Bible of notation practice.

"Only very straightforward rhythms may be written across the beat or half-bar:"[image]

It would be ridiculously pedantic to require these examples to be written with ties, simply to reveal the mid-point of the bar.  However, when the shortest note in the phrase is smaller than half of the beat, we must take more trouble to be clear.  Gould follows on with several pages of examples of acceptable and unacceptable grouping/beaming across the beat and across the half-bar.  And she frequently has to admit that usage and opinions differ.

But I think we can agree that in my example below, A is acceptable, B is not.   The jury's out on C (though it was good enough for Mozart!)[image]

Comment: C is so common that it's an exception to the rule.